# MS Access Multi User Selecting Different Records Concurrently

Tags: sql, ms-access, concurrency

In our multi-user Access environment, sometimes it is necessary to perform different actions on a group of records.  In the Orders table, for example, a user may want to delete a group of orders, or to print out a group of records, etc.  To accomplish this, in the Orders table, I created a boolean field called aSelect (the "a" is to avoid the "Select" SQL reserved keyword).  On the Orders form, users can check off the orders which they want to process by clicking the checkbox for the aSelect field and then click "print", "delete", or whatever other operation. The code behind the form then says to process the operation on all Orders WHERE ASELECT=TRUE

The problem is that, (while it hasn't happened yet), the aSelect checkbox is bound to the underlying field in the table, and two users can change aSelect at the same time.  So, suppose user A selects two records to delete, but before he hits the delete button, another user attempting to print a 100 records selects 100 records.  The result will be that all 100 records will be deleted--not the intended result.

Any solutions or alternatives?  This scenario plays out numerous times throughout the database.  The Orders table is just one example.

Thanks,

Comment: How about user id instead of/as well as a tick? You could then notify user A that user B is trying to delete their print set. BTW, I almost never allow delete, only delete flags. Alternatively, save the flag info in the front-end in a small table.

Comment: @Remou, I was hoping for a more streamlined solution.  A small front-end table is a pain, especially for multiple scenarios.  Thanks,

Comment: So what were you hoping for?

Comment: Perhaps Access is the wrong tool for this, but I know that in ADO.NET it's a disconnected model.  Perhaps there's a similar thing in Access, wherein each user can view his own "version" of the back end table without updating changes to the "real" back end table, nor having to create a separate temporary table.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Most certainly you can have disconnected data but how do you see the deletes working if they are not performed on the real data? How often would you want the user to know that there was more (or less) real data available?

Comment: Great point.  I'll have to figure that out.  In the meantime, can you point me in the right direction--how can I have disconnected data in Access?

Comment: The easiest way is to copy the back-end database from the server to the local machine.

Comment: Consider a selection form based on an ADO disconnected recordset: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14404379/77335

Comment: @HansUp, is there a way to run sql statements (select or action queries) against the in-memory recordset?  I need the equivalent of CurrentDB.Execute "DELETE * FROM " & MyDAO & " WHERE PrimaryKey In (SELECT PrimaryKey FROM " & MyADO & " WHERE Selected=TRUE;))"
Of course, LINQ to Objects would do the trick, but I'm using VBA.  Thanks.

Comment: Access SQL doesn't support a recordset object of any form for the `FROM` data source.  You could look at the ADO recordset's `.Delete` method.  Or reload the recordset from a revised query which excludes rows with  your selected primary keys: `WHERE pkey NOT IN (1, 3, 4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table with a username/userid column and an OrderID column.

When the user makes a selection, add a record to this table with the OrderID and username, then when running your query just join this selection table or use an IN() clause and filter by username.

Voila - user specific selections, which could be improved/expanded upon but this is my basic offering.

Comment: So brilliant, yet so simple.  Why didn't I think of this?